# Content query group by field

Tags: 2013, content-query-web-part

I have content query webpart that queries data from a custom list and I am using a custom xsl style to display the items everything works fine. The issue that I have is I have a column called Category which I use to group by the results of the query , I am trying to make that column clickable e.g if I have categories A, B , C , D if users click on A the link should take them to all the items under that category. Please assist

Answer (score 2):

Let you have below information:

```
<Person>
    <Student>
        <Info Country="England" Name="Rich" Age="20" Class="C" />
    </Student>
    <Student>
        <Info Country="Canada" Name="Richard" Age="20" Class="B" />
    </Student>
    <Student>
        <Info Country="England" Name="Sam" Age="21" Class="A" />
    </Student>
    <Student>
       <Info Country="Australia" Name="David" Age="22" Class="D" />
    </Student>
    <Student>
        <Info Country="Australia" Name="Andy" Age="24" Class="A" />
    </Student>
</Person>
```

Here, if you want to group by country, then you can start with below code snippet:

```
<xsl:template match="Person">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="Student/Info" group-by="@Country">
    <country name="{current-grouping-key()}">

    </country>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

Now if you want to further group the Info elements by each country group so you can group by using class

```
<xsl:template match="Person">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="Student/Info" group-by="@Country">
    <country name="{current-grouping-key()}">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="@Class">
        <student name="{current-grouping-key()}">
          <classes>
            <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
              <name><xsl:value-of select="@Name"/></name>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </classes>
        </student>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </country>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```